# Cactus still viable for Integration Testing?

Tags: cactus

I'm working on a project and we want to perform integration testing for our servlets and JSP. I was reading about the Cactus project. I was wondering if Cactus is still a viable solution for integration testing of servlets and JSPs? I know it has been around for a while and curious if there are other recent open-source projects that do a similar thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Arquillian](http://jboss.org/arquillian) looks promising.

Comment: Is Arquillian really related to JSP/Servlets testing??